# What is the right syntax for CSS "background:url" property in a Rails app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, url, background, background-image

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this image …

```
./app/assets/images/down_arrow_select.jpg
```

How do I reference this image from within a CSS file located at app/assets/stylesheets/home.css ?  I have tried this

```
 .styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(asset-path('down_arrow_select.jpg')) no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

But this doesn’t heal the pain.  If it matters, my stylesheet is included on my page like so

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "home" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprockets will only process helpers if your stylesheet file extensions are either `.css.scss` or `.css.sass.`

**So you should add `scss` or `sass` extension to your `home.css`**

Then you can try this

```
.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: asset-data-url('down_arrow_select.jpg') no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Neither of trhese solutions worked.  As noted in my question, my file already ends with ".css".  When I view the source of the CSS file in the browser, the line appears exactly as it did in did in my editor, "background: asset-data-url("down_arrow_select.jpg") no-repeat right #ddd;".  Is Rails supposed to change the line because "asset-data-url" isn't valid CSS.

Comment: Hey, the key thing is to add scss or sass extension to your css. If you use plain css extension helpers don't work with sprockets. Your file should be named home.css.scss

Comment: My bad, I read your post wrong.  Ok, I renmed my file to app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.scss but still got errors after restarting my server.  When I tried "background image-url("down_arrow_select.jpg") no-repeat right #ddd;", I got the error, 'Invalid CSS after "...ckground image-": expected "{", was "url("down_arrow..."' and when I tried, "background: asset-data-url("down_arrow_select.jpg") no-repeat right #ddd;", I got the error 'Invalid CSS after "...und asset-data-": expected "{", was "url("down_arrow..."'.